# trying to upload a file to Ftp but getting the error: "file name not allowed"!

Tags: c#, upload, ftp, webclient, public-html

So I was trying to upload a 1kb text file to my ftp server but this error comes up:

> The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.

so what's wrong with my code?

```
WebClient upload = new WebClient();
upload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("******", "*********");
upload.UploadFile("ftp://xxx.com/public_html", "G:/adress.txt");
```

Comment: What about using ftpClient instead of webclient? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell, because it's a server error not a code error.  However, as currently written, you're trying to upload the file called `adress.txt` to become a file named `public_html`.  I suspect there's already a directory with that name, and the conflict is preventing the upload.  Try

```
upload.UploadFile("ftp://xxx.com/public_html/adress.txt", "G:/adress.txt");
```

instead.

Comment: You are right I must choose the file name on the server too but don't you think if it is going to be like that firstly we need to create a file with that name on the server? like what we do in windows. first we create a file: 'File.Create()'.

Comment: @Porphan - No, `UploadFile` handles that for you.  In fact, it's quite possible that if you create the file, *then* upload it, you'll get an error preventing you from overwriting the file (depending on permissions and such).

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to you, but if it is a **Linux FTP server**:

> This may help for Linux FTP server.
>
> So, Linux FTP servers unlike IIS don't have common FTP root directory.
>   Instead, when you log on to FTP server under some user's credentials,
>   this user's root directory is used. So FTP directory hierarchy starts
>   from /root/ for root user and from /home/username for others.
>
> So, if you need to query a file not relative to user account home
>   directory, but relative to file system root, add an extra / after
>   server name. Resulting URL will look like:
>
> `ftp://servername.net//var/lalala`

Instead of:

```
ftp://xxx.com/public_html
```

You would need a second slash after the server name in addition to the full file name:

```
ftp://xxx.com//public_html/adress.txt
```

I ran into this same issue and it fixed it for me.

Source:
[Can't connect to FTP: (553) File name not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418404/cant-connect-to-ftp-553-file-name-not-allowed#answer-15200421)