# Save a file on a ftp server in a subdirectory

Tags: c#, ftp, webrequest, ftpwebrequest

I have code that allows me to access a server to do ftp transactions. I have tested the connection and it works. the problem is saving files. to help paint a picture this is how the address are set up.

**ftp server:** ftp.MyMainDomain.com

**path login ftp points to:**  www.another_website_Under_myDomain.com/gallery/images

when I tested connection, ftp server tacks me directly to images folder and I have even read the subdirectories out (`ie ..images/subdirectory1, ..images/subdirectory2`).

What I need now it to be able to save files into each of the folders. I thought that all I had to do was add `subdir` that I wanted to access to the end of the `ftp_server uri` but that doesn't work. What should I do?

```
Uri ftpUri = new Uri((Ftp_Server_Address + "/" + SubDirectory+ "/"), UriKind.Absolute);
if (ftpUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp)// check ftp address,
{
    DirRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUri);

    DirRequest.Method = ReqMethod;
    DirRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUserName, FtpPassword);
    DirRequest.UsePassive = true;
    DirRequest.UseBinary = true;
    DirRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    //change picture to stream
    Stream PicAsStream =  Pic.Bitmap_to_Stream(Pic.BitmapImage_to_Bitmap(Pic.Photo));
    //send ftp with picture
    Stream ftpReqStream = DirRequest.GetRequestStream();
    ftpReqStream = PicAsStream;
    ftpReqStream.Close();
    SendFtpRequest(ReqMethod);
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? That doesn't describe *anything* about the problem.

Comment: As stated above "What I need now it to be able to save files into each of the folders... "

Comment: So what does your code do that you don't expect? Or what does it not do that you do expect? Are you getting an error? If so, what and where? Does it save the file at all?

Comment: What error or exception occurs in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
ftpReqStream = PicAsStream;
```

You are not sending the `Stream` to `ftp Server` but you are assigning `PicAsStream` to `ftpReqStream` and then closing it. Your code does nothing.

**Do it like this:**

Create a `buffer` of your image file (not a stream):

```
FileStream ImageFileStream = File.OpenRead(your_file_path_Here);
byte[] ImageBuffer = new byte[ImageFileStream.Length];
ImageFileStream.Read(ImageBuffer, 0, ImageBuffer.Length);
ImageFileStream.Close();
```

and then simply write it to your `ftpReqStream`:

```
Stream ftpReqStream = DirRequest.GetRequestStream();
ftpReqStream.Write(ImageBuffer, 0, ImageBuffer.Length);
ftpReqStream.Close();
```

Comment: When the program get to code => line:Stream ftpReqStream = DirRequest.GetRequestStream();    it throws a "system.net.webexception; The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

Comment: I just tried it again and changed line => Uri ftpUri = new Uri((Ftp_Server_Address + "/" + SubDirectory+ "/"), UriKind.Absolute);        I removed last ((+ "/")), now it has error => system.net.webexception   The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed. Looking it up now. Also, I am working with bitmap image, i'm wondering if i will have to save it to dive then upload and delete after.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418404/cant-connect-to-ftp-553-file-name-not-allowed