# Uploading into folder in FTP?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am using the following code to learn how to load files with FTP. How do I set the path or folder into which my file will be uploaded ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folder is part of the URL you set when you create `request`: `"ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm"`. If you use `"ftp://www.contoso.com/wibble/test.htm"` then the file will be uploaded to a folder named `wibble`.

You may need to first use a request with `Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory` to make the `wibble` folder if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I was using ftp.myserver.com/myfolder. I got the error - System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Did you include the `ftp://` at the front?

Comment: I made it ftp : // myserver . com / myfolder and got the error - System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: I purposely put all those spaces in the ftp address so that SO will not convert it into a link.

Comment: The `ftp` string has two purposes and so may be needed twice: firstly as the "protocol specifier" in the beginning `"ftp://"` and secondly it may be part of the hostname of the remote server. Your earlier example had it as part of the hostname but your latest one doesn't. Should you be using `ftp://ftp.myserver.com/myfolder` ?

Comment: Note that if you use backticks to surround the address then it won't get turned into a link.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and got a new exception :( It never happens with mozilla ftp client. - System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.

Comment: Does `myfolder` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in Mozilla FTP client - as / > Fold1 > Fold2 > myfolder > fold3 etc...

Comment: Not certain then - this question has some more info about that error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418404/cant-connect-to-ftp-553-file-name-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't know the cause of my problem. I saw the second answer and it says that the default directory might be a problem. How do I find out the default directory of my server ?

Comment: Where do files end up if you don't specify any folder? That's the default.

Comment: Okay. I got my mistake. I did not include the filename in the URL.

Comment: Oh, I missed that completely while focusing on the other issues :-)