# Dynamic password in FTP task in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ftp

I can set almost all properties of FTP task and FTP connection manager using expressions option. In that option, I don't see that I can set FTP PASSWORD using a variable. How do I set the password dynamically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some approaches I looked at -

1. Use a Script to set the value of password.
2. Use a config file (no way !)
3. Use a C# script instead of the Script task. (Nice !)

(1) Link - http://wannabesoftwareengineer.blogspot.com/2009/03/setting-ftp-password-from-external.html

VB code -

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

Public Class ScriptMain

Public Sub Main()

Dim FTPConnectionManager As ConnectionManager


FTPConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("FTP_Conn")


FTPConnectionManager.Properties("ServerPassword").SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, 
Dts.Variables("FTPPassword").Value)

Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success

End Sub

End Class
```

(2) Link - [Uploading into folder in FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863737/uploading-into-folder-in-ftp)

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely use a variable as the password, within the expressions tab add an expression for the password property, you can select any variable, or parameter.