# Upload file to server .Net

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using C# .net and I am trying to upload a file to my server. I am not using asp .net.

I followed [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263518/c-sharp-uploading-files-to-file-server) and it doesn't seem to work for me. On a sidenote, this question was written back in 2008.

I am using this code as shown in the question above:

```
File.Copy("zQn69PZUx.png", "\\\\198.57.247.152\\~shiro\\public_html\\new");
//tried this also
File.Copy("zQn69PZUx.png", "\\\\198.57.247.152\\~shiro\\new");
```

The error I get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The network path was not found.
```

I also tried using my domain name and use the path like it shows up in the browser, without `http://` because it complained about the format, saying its not accepted, like this: `domain-name.com\\new`, and still got the same error as a result.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong, or have a better solution on how to upload a file to a server ? You can see here that the  http://198.57.247.152/~shiro/new/ path exists.

Comment: Is `198.57.247.152` a computer in your local network or do you only have access to it remotely?

Comment: @PeterLuu It is a shared server I have been renting from a company named hostgator. This is why the `~shiro` subfolder is for my personal use

Comment: @Sayka What do you mean by `sample` ? This is a valid link http://198.57.247.152/~shiro/new/  works on the browser

Comment: Have you setup the FTP from your hosting control panel?

Comment: If it's a shared server from a company, do you have the FTP credentials available to you for that server?

Comment: @PeterLuu Yes I do have FTP privileges, if that's the question. How else would I be able to upload my site to the server otherwise ? I can connect with Filezilla and upload files normally.

Comment: You copy files to Filezilla using this code? If yes I'll check and upvote your question. Cauz i've never seen anywhere using File.Copy for uploading..

Comment: @Sayka That's not what I meant. I replied to Peter Luu saying that I can upload files using the Filezilla client (through the interface of course), therefore I have FTP privileges I suppose.

Comment: I was more asking if you had the username and password available to you - which in this case would be yes if you can do that

Comment: That server isn't even running windows. You won't be able to use File.Copy() to an smb share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path **\\198.57.247.152\~shiro\new** is what Microsoft calls [Uniform Naming Convention (UNC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). This type of resource is only available on networks with NetBIOS enabled; essentially local network. The problem is that `File.Copy` only works if you have access to it in your network - since this is a remote server, it won't be able to find that server, leading to the `The network path was not found` exception.

**http://198.57.247.152/~shiro/new/** follows the syntax of `<scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]` which is call [Uniform resource locator (URL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) resource is typical accessed by a browsers.

You can resolve this by instead using FTP to upload your file to the server:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
     client.UploadFile("ftp://ftpserver.com/targetpath", "localfilepath");
}
```

A valid target path would be something like: ftp://localhost/samplefile.txt
and the local filepath should be the fully qualified filepath.

Comment: Yes - I'm not sure if your ftp address is the same as the 198.57.247.152 address, so I was using placeholders.

Comment: This seems to be working, kind of. I am getting this error: `the remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.` I am contacting my server hosting company right now to see what the problem is. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Have a look at this in case it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418404/cant-connect-to-ftp-553-file-name-not-allowed

Comment: Yes there has to be something about the path. Problem is I don't know the actual path since I don't have access to all the directories, because its a shared server. Hopefully I will figure this out by asking them.

Comment: ok the problem is that it needed the file name in the end as well ! (something.png for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file using code from Peter Luu's answer. But first you should have access to it.

For uploading a file to a remote server, you should be a user of it and should have a password. It is not the password you use for logging in to your Hostgator control panel. After logging into your Hostgator account, there will be an option like **FTP** in it, where you can setup FTP user accounts. There you can assign a user name and password and that have to be applied to the code for uploading..

And for checking whether the UserName and Password works, Open MyComputer, and in the addressbar type the FTP path (which will be something starting "ftp://"). There pops up a Dialog asking for UserName and Password (If the path is valid). If you enter into, See and copy files into the explorer window from there, then the uploading code will work

[image]

If you want to get the applicable path, Open windows explorer and type **ftp://your_domain_name**. Apply UserName and Password, browse through the path you need, copy it from the address bar and add it to the code.

Comment: The account definitely works because if I put a wrong password/username I get a different error inside VS2013

Comment: Yes i figured out the problem 1 second ago ! it needed the file name in the end as well in the ServerFilePathLocation !

Comment: @dimitrisdimitris, if you want to get the applicable path, Open windows explorer and type ftp://your_domain_name Apply UserName and Password, browse through the path you need, copy it from the address bar and add it to the code.

Comment: @dimitrisdimitris precede ftp:// to your domain name